# How can I plot the cumulative probability of an event occuring from a dataframe over time?

Tags: r, dataframe, probability

I want to find a general way to find the cumulative probability of an event using a dataframe output. For example, say I have a model for which I have run 3 simulations from days 0-5 which outputs this dataframe "hospital":

| Node | Time | Hospitalised |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |

I want to find and plot the cumulative probability that at least 1 person has been hospitalised over time. It is cumulative in that for each time point I care about whether there has ever been anyone in hospital for that particular simulation (currently or before the current time). The probability is for >0 hospitalised / total # simulations.

This would be the output for this simplified example

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(Node) %>%
  mutate(any_hospitalised = sign(cumsum(Hospitalised))) %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  summarize(probability = mean(any_hospitalised)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, probability)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Although you may prefer a step plot to a line plot in this scenario:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(Node) %>%
  mutate(any_hospitalised = sign(cumsum(Hospitalised))) %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  summarize(probability = mean(any_hospitalised)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, probability)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>